# Is there any official rule on Half-Construct aging?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Does adding the Half-Construct template to a race change aging in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently not! The [half-construct](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/creating-new-races#subtype-half-construct) option comes with the following:

> - Half-constructs gain a +2 racial bonus on saving throws against disease, mind-affecting effects, poison, and effects that cause either exhaustion or fatigue.
> - Half-constructs cannot be raised or resurrected.
> - Half-constructs do not breathe, eat, or sleep, unless they want to gain some beneficial effect from one of these activities. This means that a half-construct can drink potions to benefit from their effects and can sleep in order to regain spells, but neither of these activities is required for the construct to survive or stay in good health.

No aging is mentioned, which makes sense, since half-constructs are only *"artificially enhanced or have parts replaced by constructed mechanisms, be they magical or mechanical."* They're still organic to some extent, and their organic parts still age.

Strangely enough, though, the [original construct type](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Construct) doesn't mention anything about aging either.

How a particular construct or half-construct character ages may be something for the character's player to work out with their GM. If a person has only a few parts made construct, then aging will probably still affect them significantly - but if most of a their physical body has become construct, then they will probably would remain physically well far into old age as long as they can keep on affording maintenance and new parts.